# How to round off any number to the nearest multiple of 5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have been trying to round of any number to the nearest multiple of 5. By saying that, I mean that it should always round up. However, my piece of code is always to rounding off to the nearest multiple of 5 either up or down depending on the number I input. The numbers are always `int` and **whole** numbers. Here's my code:

```
num = int(input())
base = 5
for x in range(num):
    number = int(input())
    round_off = base * round(number/base)
    print(round_off)
```

The input and output:

```
in:4
in:73
out:75 #correct
in:67
out:65 #wrong, should be 70
in:38
out:40 #correct
in:33
out:35 #correct
```

As you can see, only 67 and probably others similar to that(like 57) will give me the wrong output. How can I fix my code to get the correct output?

Answer (score 1):

You need to always round *up*:

```
import math
round_off = base * math.ceil(number / base)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to round up, you can:

```
num = int(input())
if num % 5 != 0:
  num += 5
  num -= (num % 5)
```

If you want a one liner:

```
num = num if num % 5 == 0 else num + 5 - (num % 5)
```

**Note**: Both example work with a generic integral `base` value instead of 5:

```
num = num if num % base == 0 else num + base - (base % 5)
```